# How to set visiblity option in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube5.1

I am using SonarQube version 6.4. In my project there are some 25 modules and I don't want the developers to view all 25 modules, it would be easy if they can see only the ones created by them. Is there any setting such that the logged in user(author/developer) would be able to see only their own respective projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by going to the Project and then Administration > Permissions and set the project as Private.

In the Users tab, Search for the name of the user and assign the necessary rights by clicking the checkbox

[image]

You can also take a look at 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization

Comment: But after setting the project as private the author isn't able to see project only administrator could see. Is there anything else to be set?

Comment: Sorry , I couldn't find any checkboxes in users tab. Is it in the global permission or permission template tab? N thank you for the answers..

Comment: Check attached image above

Comment: Thank u sooo...much